# Not getting SQL Server Express data on other computer except in mine (host)

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, connection

I am new to Visual Studio and this is my first programming. But I stuck here, not getting the data out of my SQL Server Express database on another computer (host).

My connection string is

```
Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=loadshedding;Integrated Security=True
```

While running the application in friends computer it doesn't show any error neither shows data. Please help me I am newbie to VS and SQL Server. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two points:

1. By using the `.` in the connection string, you're telling your app to go look for the data **on your own computer** - that is not the case here - so you need to use the other computer's machine name instead - something like:

   ```
   Data Source=HOST\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=loadshedding;Integrated Security=True
   ```
2. SQL Server **Express** by default doesn't allow remote connections (connection from another computer) - so you need to make sure this is already configured properly. Search SO or Google - there are **tons** of articles and blog posts explaining how to do that.

Comment: my server name is sdp-PC then you meant sting should be like this   **Data Source=sdp-PC\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=loadshedding;Integrated Security=True **                               and i have configured remote connection settings

Comment: @Sdp: it has to be the **machine** that hosts your SQL Server Express instance (not your own machine) - so if SQL Server Express is running on `sdp-PC`, then yes, that's the connection string to use

Comment: okie i got that one but is there any way the application can run on any computers on which it is installed

Comment: oops my mistake.. sorry its working fine now thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

If your '`.\sqlexpress`' is on your computer, shouldn't you connect with a IP address from your frind's computer (SQL-Server is usally installed on a computer and then needs to be accessed via network from other computers)